# How to grab multiple files using the Dropbox Chooser?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

For a personal website I am trying to implement the Dropbox Chooser. One of the benefits is the multi-select option allowing the user to grab the links of more then one picture. When I use the < input > button and the Javascript provided on the https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser page **I can select multiple files, but it will only return one link.**

Can't really figure out how to grab all the selected files links, Google isn't helping me either. Can someone help me out? :)

Comment: it seems to work for me. are you using data-multiselect=true or multiselect: true for the button/JavaScript respectively? if so, are you just using the sample code from that page? the sample code just prints the first one as a sample, e.g.: e.files[0].link or files[0].link. the files variable is an array with everything though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var options = {
    linkType: "direct",
    multiselect: true
    success: function(files) {
      // files are here
    }
};
Dropbox.choose(options);
```

will return multiple files when after user's selection.

Comment: how to do in dropbox chooser?

Answer (score 1):

Got something that works, without using the Dropbox.choose(options) function. Looping through the array:

```
document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
    function(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++){
            $( your textarea ).append(" " + e.files[i].link);
        }
    }, false);      
});
```